# Change text from array on button click

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to display random text in array for every button click.
Couldn't figureout whats going wrong. Help me if you can solve it.

```
 $(window).ready(function(){
function quot(){
var quotes="Currently a Graduate Student in the Department of Computer Science at Northern Illinois University.@ A great lover of web programming, in search of an full-time oppurtunity to showbiz my skills and more prominently to develop myself into a master in web programming.@Apart from programming and related stuff, i play and follow sports a lot.@ I am a great soccer and cricket follower. Currently i am part of the Northern Illinois University Huskies Cricket Team that won the Midwest Regional Championship 2015.@I have great passion towards solo travelling too.";
var newArray=quotes.split("@");
var min=1;
var max=newArray.length-1;
var number=Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1))+min;
  $("#demo").text(newArray[number]);
}
quot();
$("#btn").on(click, function(){
  quot();
});
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hq7mv2zv/

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will work:

I've removed the `onclick` from the button and updated `$("#btn").on(click, function(){` to `$("#btn").on('click', function(){`

https://jsfiddle.net/hq7mv2zv/1/

Comment: Oh, My bad . Thank you so much.